# How to access recordID from lightning datatable in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I wish to navigate to a record by clicking on a button present on lightning datatable. For this, I need to access the recordId of row. I tried using `event.detail.row.id` but it does not work. I get this error: `[Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined]`. Am I doing something wrong here?

> javascript

```js
navigateToRecordViewPage(event) {

        // View a custom object record.
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: event.detail.row.Id,
                objectApiName: 'Lead', // objectApiName is optional
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }
```

> HTML

```html
<lightning-datatable
                    key-field="Id"
                    data={wrappers.data}
                    columns={columns}
                    onrowaction={navigateToRecordViewPage}
            </lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the following change in javascript function and it worked!

```js
navigateToRecordViewPage(event) {
        this.record = event.detail.row;
        // View a custom object record.
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.record.id,
                //objectApiName: 'Lead', // objectApiName is optional
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native `getSelectedRows` method of the lightning-datatable and with checkboxes enabled, you can get the ids of the rows that is clicked.

```js
handleClickAdd() {

        var el = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
        var selected = el.getSelectedRows();
        let selectedIdsArray = [];

        for (const element of selected) {
            //console.log('elementid', element.Id);
            selectedIdsArray.push(element.Id);
        }
```